# Custom download Interactive Grid to CSV in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Grid report on Oracle APEX 23.1.5 and I've added button with Dynamic Action which downloads report directly to CSV. The problem is that data in the downloaded file does not contain double quotations marks but they're required. Is there any option to include them to the file?

**Static ID of IG:** *maingrid*

**DA**: Click on Download button

**Execute Javascript Code:**

```
var ig$ = apex.region("maingrid").widget();  

ig$.interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("show-download-dialog");  

 $('.ui-button--hot').trigger("click");
```

**Current outcome:**

```
ID,Source,Version,Region,Country
1,,2.0,EMEA,CH
5,,1.0,APAC,BE
6,,1.0,APAC,AT
```

**Expected outcome:**

```
"ID","Source","Version","Region","Country"
"1","","2.0","EMEA","CH"
"5","","1.0","APAC","BE"
"6","","1.0","APAC","AT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the definition of your IG, in the Attributes to the Download section. For the CSV Format set the CSV Separator and the "CSV Enclosed By"